# sharaNAgati and anugraham in Viśiṣṭādvaita

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, vishishtadvaita

*sharaNAgati* is unconditional self-surrender to *Sriman Nārāyaṇa* and *anugraha* is the divine grace and compassion of *Perumaal* that qualifies and authenticates *bhakti*.

- According to *Viśiṣṭādvaita*, what is the relationship between the two?
- Given that one is not possible without the other, how does one break free of Saṃsāra?

Comment: I think you should also ask - How to surrender according to the scriptures? In mental, physical & verbal level.

Comment: @Rohit. Thought, Word and Deed alignment is very important. See my follow-up question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22237/acharya-sambandham-in-sri-vaishavam) that asks for the very same thing in direct accordance with Viśiṣṭādvaita.

Comment: Yes, it is indirectly asking the same. :P

Comment: @Rohit. Acc. to Sampradaya, it is direct :)

Comment: How do you people in Sri Vaishnavism define that "unconditional" thing when it comes about unconditional self-surrender to Lord Narayana?

Comment: @brahmajijnasa sarva-dharmān parityajya
mām ekaḿ śaraṇaḿ vraja
ahaḿ tvāḿ sarva-pāpebhyo
mokṣayiṣyāmi mā śucaḥ - BG 18.66