# Acharya Sambandham in Sri-Vaishnavam

Tags: vishnu, sri-vaishnava

Acharyas are the doyens of Sri-Vaishnava Sampradaya and fulfil a most important role in authoritatively vouchsafing jivAtmas trying to overcome the ocean of Saṃsāra.

What is the correct way to approach such an Acharya? What are the practices to be followed to ready oneself for the same? And God forbid, What should be one's attitude if one is deemed unready?

Comment: ......surrender

Comment: @ram but what if you need help understanding what that is?